# WSGI - PYTHON : How to determine the ** OPENED ** file's image type?

Tags: python, python-2.7, mod-wsgi, wsgi

an image and some text has been "posted" to this wsgi script.

but the image file does not have a temporary path or anything like there would be in php.

all i have in my hands is an image is all "read" already as in "opened"..

i need to find out what type of an image it is BEFORE i save it.

i need data on the file. size.. type.. etc..

```
import cgi

def application(environ, start_response):

    f = cgi.FieldStorage(environ=environ, fp=environ['wsgi.input'])

    if f:
        f1 = f['f1'].value
        f2 = f['f2'].file.read()

    if 'f2' in locals():
    f = open('/temp_image/1.png', 'w');f.write(f2);f.close()

    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/html')])
    yield 'a'
```

this will not work:

```
 a = imghdr.what('f2')
```

because

```
 imghdr.what()
```

demands a file path. but i have no such thing because file has not yet been saved.

Comment: So you only have `bytes`?

Comment: when i yield the image .. the png image loads in the browser if the image was large my browser almost freezes. that is what i have basically.

Comment: `f2 = f['f2'].file.read()` and `f2 = f['f2'].value` seems to be the same thing.. the whole png image just loads into those regardless of which one i use.

Answer (score 1):

I started to write this out but @robert-zaremba has already given a great answer to this kind of question here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14590585/101855